# How to estimate the price of an animal in a fantasy setting, or why does a duck cost more then a chicken?

Tags: economy, medieval, fauna, mathematics, avian

I realise now that this is not the right place to ask this question, but for anyone else who happens to stop by and is looking for a good reference to use to price their animals, I've found a resource that may help you:

Dwarf Fortress' animals each have a value called pet value http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/40d:Pet#Value which can be used as a good reference for pricing animals

To see a specific animal's pet value look for the tamed attributes on the page of the animal in question.
You can view all the animals here:
http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Category:DF2014:Animals

Additionally John left a good link to use for medieval prices:
http://web.archive.org/web/20110628231215/http://www.fordham.edu/halsall/source/medievalprices.html

Comment: This... seems to be asking us to give you a degree in economics with side orders of sociology, historical culture studies and animal husbandry... there are a lot of potential factors that don’t necessarily interface in a simple way.

Comment: @Joe Bloggs Good point, but as stated in the post, I'm also looking for alternatives, should I use today's prices as reference, or should I just guess as to what animals should be priced? Maybe the only solution is to study the price of each animal individually, and use those to then approximate the price of fantasy animals.

Comment: I seriously doubt that a duck would have been more expensive than a chicken in 2nd century Rome, for example. They had ducks aplenty, but chicken were exotic birds.

Comment: @AlexP That's great! Could you give me some idea of how to find these price indexes? I have tried searching myself but to only some success, I have also not been able to find prices for more exotic animals such as elephants or giraffes. Also the question could easily be rephrased as what makes a chicken cost more then a duck, but that is a good point.

Comment: [History StackExchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/). As for elephants and giraffes, that all depends on where and when you want to find prices. I don't know of any place on Earth where there was a market for both elephants and giraffes before the 19th century; and note that the market for giraffes has always been tiny and illiquid. Please remember that, for example, in Europe there has never been a market for elephants and giraffes, so that they never had a price.

Comment: I think you need to exclude exotic animals from the equation altogether. When there's such limited supply, everything depends on the supplier(s); they could be poor people trying to peddle their unwanted animals because it is all they have to sell; or it could be a shrewd businessmen with a monopoly who convinced the world that they're valuable (e.g. diamonds). I think this question could have an answer, IF you limit it to animals that are generally available on the market in question, because only then market forces will actually work and can price be reasoned about.

Comment: Why not just use real historic pricing? http://web.archive.org/web/20110628231215/http://www.fordham.edu/halsall/source/medievalprices.html

Comment: Given how complicated this is, and how much work it could take to come up with realistic price ratios, you gotta ask yourself how bad you really want this? If you only need this info to calculate the prices of meals at the local tavern, or _in case_ the players ask the hard-bargaining farmer to justify the cost of room & board, just handwave and base your price on the party's near-term revenue. Unless the prices are _central_ to your project, don't bother.

Comment: In the present day (and in the US & presumably Europe &c), ducks cost more than chickens because chickens are raised in large numbers in factory farms.  (And varieties have been selectively bred for this.)  So simply economy of scale: if you happen to raise chickens & ducks on your farm, there's not that much difference.  Likewise the price difference between beef and venison or buffalo.

Comment: Erm, ducks are  better tacticians and more devious, not to mention their wing-to-wing combat is legendary, chickens make good cannon-fodder though. This seems overly complicated, the criteria for answering are (to say the least) fuzzy like a three day old chick. Any chance of clarifying?

Comment: If you read the Help section about what makes a good question, there's this thing called the Book Test: if your question would require someone to write a book to answer it, then it's not a good fit here.  Unfortunately, this is an example of just that sort of question - since the relative values of animals will change from place to place, there's no simple answer.

Comment: "What are some general approaches" is a very very non-specific question. Please refine your question to a specific set of criteria for judging price - tell us about your society and what it's values are, it's challenges, else this is way too broad to answer. It is quite acceptable (encouraged even) to write a series of questions if you've issues which best suite that format, I'm sure this can be sorted out to your satisfaction, but it needs context and focus.

Answer (score 6):

**Think like a farmer or hunter**.
Get started by thinking of the cost of production.  How much land do you need to rent for forage?  Or how much does the food cost, for how long?  (Sometimes you get a choice - you can lock the cow in a pen and feed it, or leave it "free range", with a modest difference in cost)  If the animal is wild caught, think of how long it will take to hunt one - which depends on how many people are hunting them.  Lobster was once considered a food for the poor, a scavenger that was easily caught.  Then demand increased and so did the work needed to catch one.

Last but not least, don't forget to price in market distortions.  The farmer may not get nearly as much money as the consumer has to pay, depending on how tightly the market and transportation of food is controlled.  Farmers as a whole may be chronically in debt, so much of the cash that reaches them may be going to the bank.  Chancy distribution could mean that animals are lost or meat spoiled.  Additionally, the price could be elevated by monopoly tactics or if the demand for the animal is increasing faster than it can reproduce.

If you compare [raising ducks](http://www.suburbanhomesteading.com/raising-ducks-for-meat/barn) to [raising chickens](https://oldclayfarm.com/top-5-broiler-chicken-breeds-for-meat-production/), it becomes clear that in the real world there are many different considerations.  You'd need a real farmer to give you reliable specifics, but just look through some of this!  The chickens may actually need *longer* than the ducks to mature, but they can be kept in a smaller space and can be raised for egg production with their meat being only a nice extra.  (But why aren't duck eggs comparable...?)  The "conversion ratio" may be 2 pounds of feed for a chicken per pound, versus 3 for a duck.  All these specifics affect the price.

It may be easiest for you to get real world prices for each meat, then alter them according to what is different in your fantasy scenario.